# Android Studio Unresolved Reference on Data Binding classes

Tags: android-studio, data-binding

After upgrading my android studio to 3.5, my data binding classes are showing unresolved references. I've tried rebuilding my project, invalidating caches and restart the ide. I've checked my dependencies and it is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

...

// Enables data binding.
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

But it is still not working. Can someone help ?

Comment: What references exactly are unresolved?

Comment: When i am using binding.A_VIEW, the view is unresolved. This happened when i updated my android studio to 3.5.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: I did. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please paste the code that is producing the error?